Multirow in table bigger than single rows
How can I adjust the height of the cells here? I also would like to have a little space above and below the matrices and I want that the rows after the matrices are vertically centered?
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts,amsthm,mathrsfs}

\begin{document}


\begin{table} 
\centering
\begin{tabular}{ccccc}
hello & & \multicolumn{3}{c}{hello} \\ 
\multirow{2}{*}{$\begin{pmatrix}0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}$} & $a$ & $0$ & $0$ & $0$ \\ & $a$  & $0$ & $0$ & $0$ \\ \hline 
\multirow{2}{*}{$\begin{pmatrix}0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}$} & $a$ & $0$ & $0$ & $0$ \\ & $a$  & $0$ & $0$ & $0$ \\ \hline 
\end{tabular} 
\end{table}


\end{document}

The current output is


\multirow basically overlaps whatever is below it.  One can achieve the same effect using \raisebox, although you will have to compute the distances needed.

You got three answers which try to solve your problem. You may now consider to accept one of them (by clicking on the check mark at top left side of answer) which you the most liked. BRW, as I sow, so far you not accepted any of received answers ...

Like this?

Instead of tabular package I would rather use tblr of tabularray package on the following way without use of multi row cells:
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsthm,
            mathrsfs}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tblr}{colspec={ Q[c, mode=math]
                           Q[c, m]
                           *{3}{Q[c,m]} },
                 row{1} = {mode=text}
                 }
hello &         &       &   hello 
                                    &           &           \\ 
\begin{pmatrix}
    0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
    0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
    0 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}   & {$a$\\$a$}   
                        & {0\\ 0}   & {0\\ 0}   & {0\\ 0}   \\ 
    \hline 
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}   & {$a$\\$a$}  
                        & {0\\ 0}   & {0\\ 0}   & {0\\ 0}   \\ 
    \hline 
    \end{tblr} 
\end{document}


Have a look at the tabularray package - it makes it easy to merge cells:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts,amsthm,mathrsfs}

\begin{document}


\begin{table} 
\centering
\begin{tblr}{
  cells={halign=c},
  vspan=even
}
hello & & \SetCell[c=3]{}hello \\ 
\SetCell[r=2]{} $\begin{pmatrix}0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}$ & $a$ & $0$ & $0$ & $0$ \\ & $a$  & $0$ & $0$ & $0$ \\ \hline 
\SetCell[r=2]{} $\begin{pmatrix}0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}$ & $a$ & $0$ & $0$ & $0$ \\ & $a$  & $0$ & $0$ & $0$ \\ \hline 
\end{tblr} 
\end{table}


\end{document}



Can I get the two lines in the last row after the matrix more centered?

With "more centred" you mean closer together?

Yes, closer towards the middle of the cell.

@esner1994 If you want them closer to the middle, add an extra row above and below

I suggest you use nested matrix and pmatrix environments. No need to fiddle with \multirow directives. And, by using \midrule and \bottomrule, two macros provided by the booktabs package, one can meet your following objective:

I also would like to have a little space above and below the matrices



\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}  % for '\text' macro and 'matrix' and 'pmatrix' environments
\usepackage{booktabs} % for well-spaced horizontal rules ('\midrule', '\bottomrule')

\begin{document}
\[
\begin{matrix} % "outer" matrix
\text{hello} & \text{hello} \\ 
\begin{pmatrix} % row 1, first "inner" matrix
  0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
  0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
  0 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix} &
\begin{matrix} % row 1, second "inner" matrix
  a & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
  a & 0 & 0 & 0 
\end{matrix} \\
\midrule 
\begin{pmatrix} % row 2, first "inner" matrix
  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
  0 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix} &
\begin{matrix} % row 2, second "inner" matrix
  a & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
  a & 0 & 0 & 0 
\end{matrix} \\ 
\bottomrule 
\end{matrix} % end of "outer" matrix
\]
\end{document}

